# Software which can send and also recieve those sent mails from localhost

Tags: email

I was using a software which can send mails from localhost and then receive those sent e-mails and shows me that. and I was able to be sure that my application's mail function is working properly.

But recently my HDD crashes and I lost all of my previous data.. So now I am searching again for that software but the thing is I just forgot the name of that..

Is there anyone who use this kind of software before...?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just asking for a script while showing no willingness to learn how to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might mean "Papercut":

http://papercut.codeplex.com/

Comment: It's a similler software to papercut. Though tried papercut not works.......

Comment: http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: yes thatz the thing.. thanks bro... though already done my job... :)